# how to get control bounds relative to the wizard

Tags: java, jface, composite

I hope I can explain my problem.
I am working on a dialog that can contain number of trees from left side, and one tree from right side. 
I need to draw a line from left to right, but for some reason, I am getting the same tree item bounds.
For example, when the first item is selected in tree one it will return the same bounds location for the first item in tree two. 
How do I get item bounds relative to the wizard and not to the composite.

Here is the code:

```
import org.eclipse.draw2d.ColorConstants;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;

public class SWTSashForm
{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);


        Composite composite = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        composite.setBackground(ColorConstants.white);


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            Label lbl = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
            lbl.setText("Tree " + i);

            // Configure scrolled composite
            ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(composite, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
            scrolledComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
            scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
            scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
            scrolledComposite.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
            scrolledComposite.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

            // Add content to scrolled composite
            Composite scrolledContent = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
            scrolledContent.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            GridData gridData = new GridData();
            gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
            gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
            gridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
            gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
            scrolledContent.setLayoutData(gridData);
            scrolledComposite.setContent(scrolledContent);

            final TreeViewer tree = new TreeViewer(scrolledContent);
            for(int loopIndex0 = 0; loopIndex0 < 10; loopIndex0++) {
                TreeItem treeItem0 = new TreeItem(tree.getTree(), 0);
                treeItem0.setText("Level 0 Item "+ loopIndex0);

                for(int loopIndex1 = 0; loopIndex1 < 10; loopIndex1++) {
                    TreeItem treeItem1 = new TreeItem(treeItem0, 0);
                    treeItem1.setText("Level 1 Item "+ loopIndex1);

                    for(int loopIndex2 = 0; loopIndex2 < 10; loopIndex2++) {
                        TreeItem treeItem2 = new TreeItem(treeItem1, 0);
                        treeItem2.setText("Level 2 Item "+ loopIndex2);
                    }
                }
            }
            tree.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


            tree.getTree().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                    TreeItem[] selection = tree.getTree().getSelection();
                    for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                        TreeItem item = selection[i];
                        Rectangle bounds = item.getBounds();
                        System.out.println("Tree item bounds y " + bounds.y  );
                    }
                } });
        }
        new TreeViewer(sashForm);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item bounds is always relative to the parent tree.

You can convert the position to be relative to the display using:

```
Point displayPos = tree.getTree().toDisplay(bounds.x, bounds.y);
```

and then convert this position to be relative to another control (such as your shell) using:

```
Point pos = shell.toControl(displayPos);
```